# Enum dependency property never updates from the view

Tags: wpf, enums, dependency-properties

I have a dependency property on a usercontrol that is an enum. I bind to it and set it in the main window view but it does not change.

This is the usercontrol and the icon is the enum

```
<local:GoogleMaterialIcon Icon="AccountBalance"/>
```

Here is the enum

```
public enum Icon
{
    _3DRotation,
    Accessibility
};
```

here is the dp

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Dependency Property used to back the <see cref="Icon"/> Property
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Icon",
            typeof(Icon),
            typeof(GoogleMaterialIcon),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

and finally the property

```
public Icon Icon
{
    get { return (Icon)GetValue(IconProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(IconProperty, value);
    }
}
```

I place a breakpoint inside the set icon but it never runs. also the enum is in its own file. every time i run it shows me the wrong icon because the dp reverts to the first enum and never updates

update: full code of the usercontrol behind

```
public partial class GoogleMaterialIcon : UserControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Dependency Property used to back the <see cref="Icon"/> Property
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Icon",
            typeof(Icon),
            typeof(GoogleMaterialIcon),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));


    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public GoogleMaterialIcon()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Select a predefined icon to use 
    /// </summary>
    public Icon Icon
    {
        get { return (Icon)GetValue(IconProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IconProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: added the behind code of the usercontrol. i dont use the property in the view yet. the idea would be to do something during the setter of Icon

Comment: in your `PropertyMetadata` you are missing the PropertyChanged-Event. Oh and you should actually **bind** your property to the correct type. Not only set a string

Comment: I dont have to add this normally. is this something special for an enum?

Comment: this worked thank you, but i still dont see why when ive been doing loads of dp latelt and not once needed this :s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviosly under some - at least for me - strange circumstances, even [Microsoft](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ed347774-1b3d-48ca-8298-c251300841f1/mvvm-binding-enum-to-comboboxes-value-not-updating-after-change?forum=wpf) only comes up with an solution rather than an explanation.

In your PropertyMetadata you are missing the `PropertyChanged`-Event

Unfortunately i cannot explain in deep, whats happening here. But using the `PropertyChanged`-Event of the DependencyProperty seems for me an acceptable workaround.

Comment: the property changed event works, could you put that as an answer and i'll mark it for the question thanks, just for clarity sake i tried the positive value, it didn't work unfortunately